# solving this multi-step equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Alright, so I'm confused.
I have $\frac{1}{2}x + 2 = 4$. To solve it, I multiplied the right side by two and got $x + 4 = 4$, however, that would give me $0$ as my answer. When I subtract the two first, I get $4$ as my answer.

Do I have to do the same to all sides of the equation or only one? So do I multiply everything by $2$ to get $x + 4 = 8$?

Answer (score 1):

You need to treat both sides of the equation the same (since they *are* the same), or you no longer get to *call* them the same (that is, you have to stop using the $=$ sign, which would be bad). For example, $1+2=3$ is true, but if we multiply the *left* side by $2,$ we get the false equation $2+4=3.$

You should multiply both sides by $2,$ as you say, to get $x+4=8.$